# Exact Hook to payment methods

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using this hook `woocommerce_order_status_processing` to check if an order is payed and update the user with a memberplan. The problem is that manual update, acessing *woocommerce menu > orders > change status* from any to processing works, but when the online payment returns and change the status programatically appears that the hook `woocommerce_order_status_processing` is not being used and my client's status is not being changed. How I can find which hook I need to use? Someone have a tip?

Comment: What did you mean with "when the online payment returns"?

Comment: Think paypal. If paypal is processing the order they return a value and woocommerce update the order. When this is ocurring my function is not being called. But if I access my wp-admin, go to the order and manually change the status my function is called. I think is something with the hook I'm using.

Comment: Have you looked in the code of your payment plugin? Which one do you use?

Comment: Yes. I looked before but somehow looking again now I discovered the correct hook. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said before change manually the data through admin works well with the `woocommerce_order_status_processing` hook. But the gateway I'm using was using other method and consequently other hook. The right hook is `woocommerce_update_order`.

Inside this hook was needed to use a conditional check if the `status` change to processing.

```
public function create_memberplan_after_update_order($order){
    $order = wc_get_order($order);
    if ($order->data['status'] == 'processing') {
        //update user when status is changed to processing
    }
}
```